# Which direction is the lsb and the msb for MIPS?

Tags: mips

Which direction is the lsb(least signficant bit) and the msb(most significant bit) for mips?

for example if i have a 32-bit hex decimal 0x12345678, Would this be correct for the for the 4 (least and most) significant bits?

LSB = 0x00005678

MSB = 0x12340000

Answer (score 3):

You may not have realized it, but you've asked a trick question: the MIPS can be configured as either little-endian or big-endian.

You can determine which via code: assign 1 to a 32-bit integer variable, and the 1 will be where the least-significant bit goes, with all of the other bits 0.

Comment: well which is the default? is there not a default?

Comment: i am trying to create a function that takes two 32bit int arguments gets the 16 lsb of each and stores both 16bits into the upper and lower of a 32 bit int result

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hunter gave you the correct answer. But, based upon your comment:

> i am trying to create a function that takes two 32bit int arguments gets the 16 lsb of each and stores both 16bits into the upper and lower of a 32 bit int result

I don't think endianness comes into it because your function will have the values in *registers* already, so the problem is the *same* regardless of endianness.

Here's a program that implements your function:

```
# swap -- combine two 32 bit integers lower 16 bits

    .data
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

    .text

    .globl  main

main:
    li      $a2,0x01020304
    move    $a0,$a2
    jal     print

    li      $a3,0x05060708
    move    $a0,$a3
    jal     print

    move    $a0,$a2
    move    $a1,$a3
    jal     swap

    move    $a0,$v0
    jal     print

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# swap -- combine lower 16 bits of two arguments into single 32 bit number
#
# arguments:
#   a0,a1
#
# returns:
#   v0 = ((a0 & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (a1 & 0xFFFF)
#
swap:
    li      $v0,0xFFFF                  # get mask
    and     $a0,$a0,$v0                 # isolate lower 16 bits
    and     $a1,$a1,$v0                 # isolate lower 16 bits

    sll     $v0,$a0,16                  # retval = arg1 << 16
    or      $v0,$v0,$a1                 # retval |= arg2

    jr      $ra

# print -- print a number in hex
print:
    li      $v0,34
    syscall

    la      $a0,msg_nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    jr      $ra
```

---

Here is the output of that program:

```
0x01020304
0x05060708
0x03040708
```

---

But, just to add to Scott's answer, here's a program to calculate the endianness. Just extract the `endian` function and add it to your code:

```
# endian -- calculate endian
    .data
endian_data:    .word   0

msg_pre:    .asciiz     "machine is "
msg_big:    .asciiz     "big"
msg_little: .asciiz     "little"
msg_fin:    .asciiz     " endian\n"

    .text

    .globl  main

main:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_pre
    syscall

    jal     endian

    bnez    $v0,main_big
    la      $a0,msg_little
    j       main_exit

main_big:
    la      $a0,msg_big

main_exit:
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    la      $a0,msg_fin
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# endian -- determine big-endian or little-endian
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- 0=little, 1=big
endian:
    li      $v0,1
    sw      $v0,endian_data
    lb      $v0,endian_data
    jr      $ra
```